# @Autowired using the wrong implementation despite @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I followed a tutorial I found online to use `@ConditionalOnProperty` with `@Bean` to choose an implementation for `@Autowired`.

For completeness (though it isn't relevant to the issue), the purpose of this is to choose an "ICE Server List" provider - either as configured locally in a config file or using the Twilio API to get a list of STUN and TURN servers for WebRTC.

Here is the relevant code:

## `application.properties`

```
ice.provider = twilio
```

## `Controller.java`

```
@ComponentScan
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSocket
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private IceProvider iceProvider;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "ice.provider", havingValue = "local")
    public IceProvider localIceProvider() {
        logger.info("Creating ICE server provider - LOCAL");
        return new LocalIceProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "ice.provider", havingValue = "twilio")
    public IceProvider twilioIceProvider() {
        logger.info("Creating ICE server provider - TWILIO");
        return new TwilioIceProvider();
    }
}
```

## `IceProvider.java`

```
public interface IceProvider {
    List<ICEServer> getIceServers(String username);
}
```

## `LocalIceProvider.java`

```
@Component
public class LocalIceProvider implements IceProvider {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LocalIceProvider.class);

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        logger.info("Reading local ICE Server list config file");

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public List<ICEServer> getIceServers(String username) {
        logger.info("Returning locally configured ICE servers");

        // ...    
    }
}
```

## `TwilioIceProvider.java`

```
@Component
public class TwilioIceProvider implements IceProvider {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TwilioIceProvider.class);

    @Override
    public List<ICEServer> getIceServers(String username) {
        logger.info("Doing Twilio API call and returning result");

        // ...
    }
}
```

Despite the `application.properties` setting to use the `twilio` provider, the application is using the `local` provider.  However, **only** the `twilioIceProvider` factory method is being called, not the `localIceProvider` method.

Here is a snippet from the logs:

### On application start

Both the `@PostConstruct` method of `LocalIceProvider` and the factory method of `TwilioIceProvider` are called, but not the factory method of `LocalIceProvider`

```
...
[2017-12-31 21:11:53 INFO ] [localhost-startStop-1] [ice.LocalIceProvider] Reading local ICE Server list config file
...
[2017-12-31 21:11:55 INFO ] [main] [com.example.Controller] Creating ICE server provider - TWILIO
...
```

### On a request from the client that calls `iceProvider.getIceServers()`

```
[2017-12-31 21:14:40 INFO ] [http-nio-9083-exec-5] [ice.LocalIceProvider] Returning locally configured ICE servers
```

Since only the `twilioIceProvider` factory method is being called **and the `localIceProvider` method is not**, why is the `LocalIceProvider` being `@Autowired`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@Component` annotations from your `IceProvider` implementations. You are already declaring them as beans using `@Bean` on the bean definition methods.